# Strange row reduction method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image]

This is a determinant problem with the solution. But I don't understand what sort of row reduction is being used or why. I can see the first term of each row is being subtracted from the others, but why?

Answer (score 4):

The first step
$$
{\det}\!\pmatrix{
1&1&1\\
x&y&z\\
x^2&y^2&z^2\\
}
=
{\det}\!\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
x&y-x&z-x\\
x^2&y^2-x^2&z^2-x^2\\
}
$$
is a column reduction, not a row reduction. The first column is subtracted from each of the other columns.

As to why it's a good move? Leaving only one nonzero entry in the first row instantly reduces the problem to a $2{\times}2$ determinant. Moreover, it produces common factors in the second and third columns, so it's not just a good move, it's a great move.

The next step
$$
{\det}\!\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
x&y-x&z-x\\
x^2&y^2-x^2&z^2-x^2\\
}
=
(y-x)(z-x)\;{\det}\!\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
x&1&1\\
x^2&y+x&z+x\\
}
$$
removes the common factor $y-x$ from the second column, and the common factor $z-x$ from the third column.

The next step 
$$
(y-x)(z-x)\;{\det}\!\pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
x&1&1\\
x^2&y+x&z+x\\
}
=
(y-x)(z-x)\;{\det}\!\pmatrix{
1&1\\
y+x&z+x\\
}
$$
is expansion along the first row.

Expanding the $2{\times}2$ determinant yields the final answer.